# we can 't read some files that are required to run the Magento application. This usually means file permissions are set incorrectly

Tags: magento2, aws

[I have changed some file permission
Now my website is giving me error
we can 't read some files that are required to run the Magento application. This usually means file permissions are set incorrectly.

When I run `php bin/magento cache:clean`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface in /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#1 /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Config.php(345): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Config.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Config->getSerializer()
#3 /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(84): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Config->extend(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/Environment/Developer.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->configure(Array)
#5  in /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

Pic of My file permission

[image]

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12844 - check with this.

Comment: Thank you I think this is the permission issue -not version issue

Comment: Can you see last 2 folders permission  var and vendor drwxr-sr-x i tied with sudo but its not changing .Is this right permission ? or it suppose to be drwxr-xr-x. or are they both same ? Thank you

Comment: generally var pub and generated have 777 permission.

Comment: I tried not working